# use eratosthenes sieve to find prime

Tags: android

hello i want my app find prime between two number with sieve algorithm i am use this code but its not working well what can i do for improve this code to my goal please help me

```
public int[] GetPrimes() {

    int[] primesData = new int[maxValue+1];
    int[] results    = new int[maxValue];

    int i;
    int result_count = 0;

    for (i=MIN_VALUE; i<=maxValue; i++) {
        primesData[i] = PRIME_UNKNOWN;
    }
    for (i=MIN_VALUE; i<=maxValue; i++) {
        if (primesData[i] == PRIME_UNKNOWN) {
            primesData[i] = PRIME_YES;
            results[result_count++] = i;
            int j;
            for (j=i; j<=maxValue; j = j + i) {
                primesData[j] = PRIME_NO;
            }
        }
    }

    int[] retval = new int[result_count];
    for (i=0; i<result_count; i++) {
        retval[i] = results[i];


    }

    tvresult.setText(retval.toString());
    return retval;



}
```

}

Comment: define `not working well`

Comment: for example my output is I@4051f860

Comment: what shuold i do please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is correct. Likely you are launching it with wrong values as input.

Ensure to have `MIN_VALUE` set to value `2` and prepopulate `retval` with `1` i.e.:

```
int[] retval = new int[result_count+1];
retval[0] = 1;
for (i=0; i<result_count; i++) {
    retval[i+1] = results[i];
```

For the printing issue:

```
tvresult.setText(Arrays.toString(retval));
```

Because `retval.toString()` just returns the object reference not the content. This is true for any Java array. Instead use [Arrays.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29).

Comment: thanks for answer but i am not know why retreval present like this [I@4051f1b0